# SELECT an Xml variable into a table

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a variable called `result` of type *Xml* that contains one cell of Xml text. I cannot seem to use `SELECT INTO` to insert this value into another temp table.

```
SELECT @result
INTO dbo.xml_temp
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @LukStorms you mean something like `SELECT @result AS XmlOutput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert the XML into an existing table, you have

- `VALUES`
- or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`:

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,TargetColumn XML);

DECLARE @SomeXML XML ='<root>test</root>';

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(@SomeXML);

INSERT INTO  @tbl(TargetColumn) SELECT @SomeXML;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

If you really want to **create a new temp table**, your statement is just missing an alias (How should the new table know the column's name?):

```
SELECT @SomeXML AS SomeName INTO #tmpTable;
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable;
```